# using gulp to setup a local webserver

Tags: webserver, gulp

I come from a grunt background. And setting up a web server was as easy as `grunt connect`.

I would put following code in my grunt file and run `grunt connect`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        // fire up the local server
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9778, //port to host on
                    livereload: 35729,
                    hostname: '0.0.0.0', //the hostname
                    base: 'out/' //the relative path from grunt file to base folder of web app
                }
            }
        }
    });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
```

My situation changed as I had to migrate to gulp. But I cant get it work in gulp. May be it is because of my background. I am using [gulp-webserver](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver). And added my gulp file is as follows:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  gulp.src('app')
    .pipe(webserver({
      path:'dist',
      port:'9090',
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: true,
      open: true
    }));
});
```

When I navigate to `localhost:9090`, I get the response: `cannot GET /`

What am I doing wrong? Isnt the path relative path from gulp file? What am I supposed to pass to `gulp.src`? It would be a great help if somebody could give me a headstart where to look at.

**EDIT 1**
my gulpfile, src folder and the folder after build, ie the dist folder all are in same level.

```
├── src       // my raw application folder
├── dist      // application folder after building
|   .
|   .
|   └── index.html
└── gulpfile.js
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

mostly it means its not finding index.html

```
return gulp.src('./app/')
  .pipe(plugin.webserver({
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 6639,
      livereload: true,
      open: true,
      fallback: './dist/index.html'
  }));
```

mostly its the problem with the path setting.. try below in ur case

```
  gulp.src('dist')
    .pipe(webserver({
         ......
    }));
```

Comment: I am not currently at my work desk. so I will try it soon as I get there. Could you explain what is the sources.debug passed to src() and what is the function mainly used for? I am a little bit confused here.

Comment: sorry for confusing you.. `sources.debug` is basically a variable name.. i dont hardcode paths, keep them in variables

Comment: i dont know what i did wrong. it is still showing the same error. may be I am missing something. I will update the information.

Comment: does your app folder contains index.html and not the dist.. path variable is for `localhost:port/path` its not file path, remove path setting

Comment: I had the same problem/misunderstanding. The docs should be a little more explicit. Install the webserver below the root, then put the root folder name in the gulp.src() line. In this case, the root folder is 'app' so gulp.src('app').etc... Once I did that everything fell into place.

Comment: For my situation, after half-an-hour challenge, it was to switch directoryListing to false

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when I was inadvertently starting the webserver right after my clean task so the directory didn't actually exist because it had just been removed.  The problem was here:

```
gulp.task('watch', ["build", "webserver"]);
```

Which was starting the **build** task first, which was starting a clean task before it ran.

```
gulp.task('build', ["clean"])
```

To fix this I switched to starting the webserver inside the watch task instead of a dependency of the watch task

```
gulp.task('watch', ["build"], function() {
    return gulp.start(['webserver']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, after half-an-hour challenge, it was to switch **directoryListing** to **false**:

```
gulp.task('webserver', () => {
    return gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(webserver({
            port: 8000,
            livereload: true,
            directoryListing: false,
            open: true,
            fallback: './dist/index.html'
        }));
});
```

So get rid of that option **directoryListing**!